# How to delete a type of character in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**Here's my data:**

```
No   Name   
1    'hg    
2    'ho'c    
3    hgy
```

I would like to remove `'` character. Here's the expected output:

```
No   Name   
1    hg    
2    hoc    
3    hgy
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you to replace ' with basically nothing, this could be done using the following code:

`df["Name"].str.replace("\'","")`

Hope this solves your issue.

Comment: `replce` or `replace` ?

Comment: Great :) if my answered helped please make sure to accept it (by ticking the grey tick near my answer)

Comment: Yes but the \ should not be necessary here, simply: `"'"`. Another alternative would be to do: `df.Name.replace("'","", regex=True)`